# wp_mail BCC admin

Tags: wp-mail

This code does exactly what I want, but I want to add the username of the author of the post.

```
// BCC Admin
if (get_option('jr_bcc_apply_emails')=='yes') :
    wp_mail( get_option('admin_email'), __('[copy] going for "', APP_TD).$post->post_title.'"',  $message, '', $attachments );
endif;
```

I tried the `id_author` almost everywhere but it doesn't work:

```
.., APP_TD).$post->post_title.'".$post->id_author',  $message, '', $attachments );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$post->post_author will return the ID of the post author, which you can then use with the WP_User object to retrieve the username and add to the outgoing email:

```
if (get_option('jr_bcc_apply_emails')=='yes') :
  $author = new WP_User( $post->post_author );
  $username = $author->user_login;
  $to = get_option('admin_email');
  $subject = __('[copy] going for "', APP_TD).$post->post_title.'"';
  $message .+ " {$username}";
  wp_mail( $to, $subject,  $message, '', $attachments );
endif;
```

[Codex: WP_Post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post)

[Codex: WP_User](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried to insert that but when i receive the email i don't have that data. 
Probably is just a matter of position in that function but i tried everything that i know and nothing appears

Comment: I've updated my answer to include your code updated with the username added to the subject.

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thank you for your help!
Your code worked but like you said appears in the subject the name of the author and if i put after or before the message i don't receive the attached files. It's normal?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the author's name after the message (and also formatted for clarity).